# Spring cloud config client load local properties if the config server is down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to access the spring cloud config server but it is down. I still want to test the application using local **application.properties**. Is there any way i could do this?

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8086
spring:
  application:
    name: PromoMS
  security:
    basic:
      enabled: false
    management:
      security:
        enabled: false
  cloud:
    config:
      fail-fast: true
      discovery:
        enabled: true
        service-id: ms-config-server
```

I am getting following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances found of configserver (ms-config-server)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerInstanceProvider.getConfigServerInstances(ConfigServerInstanceProvider.java:48) ~[spring-cloud-config-client-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: try commenting `spring-cloud-starter-config` from pom

Comment: At the application startup if the config server is down then it should go and access the local properties. In this way it wont access cloud-server any time.

Answer (score 0):

To disable spring-cloud-config you and use your local properties, you need to add this property to your `bootstrap.yml`:

```
spring.cloud.config.enabled=false
```

And then enable it only when you need to run your application via application args, something like this:

```
java -jar your-application-name.jar --spring.cloud.config.enabled=true
```

Comment: **spring.cloud.config.enabled=false** i don't want to this at the same time e.g. at the application startup if the config server is available then load property from there else load the local properties.